# Why is using the base key word causing this error?

Tags: f#

I am trying to do an example for Programming F# by O'Railey, Chris Smith page 53.

It is working with functions returning functions.

This line straight from the book in the VS2013 IDE Editor, FSI and LinqPad4 are giving an error:

Code:

```
let generatePowerOfFunc base = (fun exponent -> base ** exponent)
```

Error:

```
error FS0010: Unexpected keyword 'base' in pattern
```

What am I missing or is there something the author did not include that needs to be included.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I strongly suspect it's merely a matter of `base` not being a keyword when the book was written.

Try a different identifier:

```
let generatePowerOfFunc b = (fun exponent -> b ** exponent)
```

Assuming you've got the 2009 edition of Programming F#, that would be before F# 2.0 was released (although after 1.0). I'm trying to find out exactly when it was introduced as a keyword...

EDIT: Actually, looking at [this version of the spec](http://7explications.wordpress.com/category/f/f-language-specification/) which was written in 2009, it looks like `base` was already a keyword at that point. I wonder whether the original code was written significantly before the book was published.

Either way, I think it's reasonable to treat it basically as an error, and using a valid identifier instead should be fine.

EDIT: It's actually listed in the [book's errata](http://oreilly.com/catalog/errata.csp?isbn=9780596153649):

> Example 3-3 does not work as-is in VS 2010.  "base" is apparently a keyword, so it should have been escaped or there is some voodoo to make it not a keyword that I've missed in the book.  Line 2 of the example should look like this:
>
> ```
>    let generatePowerOfFunc ``base`` = (fun exponent -> ``base`` ** exponent);;
> ```
>
> Alternatively, a different variable name should be chosen.
>
> Note from the Author or Editor:
> Thanks for the feedback, I must have missed the keyword being marked as reserved late in the product cycle.
>
> In a future version of the book I'll have it read:
>
> ```
>  let generatePowerOfFunc baseValue = (fun exponent -> baseValue ** exponent);;
> ```

Comment: Lulz you know if I just thought about that for a second I could have figured that out. Guess I been staring at this book for too long time for a break.

Comment: I thought he was trying to use the keyword for a purpose but I didn't see past the squiggly red line.

Comment: @Cubicle.Jockey: See my edit for the quote from the official errata. You can quote the keyword, or just use a different identifier.

Comment: Yeah thanks for being a ninja. I would have selected yours as the answer like 8 minutes ago but I have to wait. :)

Answer (score 3):

`base` in F# is a keyword, which refers to the parent class.

Either you can use double backticks  as follows

```
let generatePowerOfFunc ``base`` = (fun exponent -> ``base`` ** exponent);;
```

or just change the name of the argument to something else.